# How to use Windows 10 features in WPF app

Tags: c#, xaml

Is there a way to use features from Windows 10 in standard WPF app, built in Windows 8.1?
I'm building app that will use built in webcam, that feature is required only when using Windows 10 tablet, desktop PCs won't use it. I've found "MediaCapture API" for Windows 10 and it would work perfectly, but I have no idea how to use it without creating new project dedicated for UWP.

[MediaCapture API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh452758.aspx)

Comment: It would be a good idea to clarify your question further. What do you consider a "standard Windows app" versus a UWP app? Also provide a link to the MediaCapture API

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this subset of WinRT APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn554295(v=vs.85).aspx) in desktop applications.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/10/02/using-windows-8-winrt-apis-in-net-desktop-applications.aspx) is an instruction that shows how to reference winmd assembly from desktop application.